# How do I get Travis' build working directory in .travis.yml?

Tags: travis-ci

When working with the .travis.yml, is there an environment variable that contains the name of the current build directory in Travis-CI?  Looking through the docs [here](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/ci-environment/#Environment-variables) I don't see one.

Comment: It would be really nice if you would accept the correct answer, just to make it easier to spot it.

Comment: Best comment for a question only have 1 answer ;)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You probably want `$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR`, which is the directory we clone the repository to and `cd` into afterwards, before running your tests.

Comment: Documented at: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Environment-variables

Comment: Has this changed? It seems to be that `$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR` _is_ the repo dir, i.e. has a `.git` directory.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my answer may not have been totally clear on that: `$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR` is the directory that contains your checked-out code (i.e. `$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/.git` exists), and is the working directory when your commands start to run.

Comment: Now documented at https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/