# How to specify a build folder in Travis?

Tags: travis-ci

I have a github repository `user/repo` but the real project is in a subfolder `user/repo/project/build.sbt`
What should I write in the `.travis.yml` to make Travis ignore the top folder and work only in the project folder?

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006810/how-do-i-get-travis-build-working-directory-in-travis-yml) I tried the following which didn't work:

```
env:
  global:
    - REPO="user/repo"
    - CI_HOME=`pwd`/$REPO
script: sh -c 'cd $CI_HOME/project' && sbt ++$TRAVIS_SCALA_VERSION package
```

Error log:

```
$ sh -c 'cd $CI_HOME/project' && sbt ++$TRAVIS_SCALA_VERSION package
Detected sbt version 0.12.2-RC1
/home/travis/build/user/repo doesn't appear to be an sbt project.
```

Ideally there should be a way to specify the build folder but let Travis handle the build command.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just write a shell script and use this to build your project. Make sure it works locally.
Something like this should do the trick:

`build.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/project
sbt ++$TRAVIS_SCALA_VERSION package
```

`.travis.yml`:

```
script: build.sh
```

Comment: also needs a chmod on build.sh otherwise "permission denied"

Comment: what's the ++$TRAVIS_SCALA_VERSION for? Telling travis what version of scala to use? Not sure how to run this locally?

Comment: This is not relevant here, `build.sh` can contain anything. Make sure the `build.sh` runs locally. If this is the case, then you can use it to tell travis what to do when running a build job.

Comment: The answer from @iIOCowboy is clearly much better and has 10x the upvotes.

Answer (score 123):

You could also try adding the following line in your **.travis.yml** file:

```
before_script: cd project
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. The solution currently marked as correct should be changed to this one.

Answer (score 48):

I tried using this in my travis.yml file but didnt work

```
before_script: cd project
```

Then i tried this

```
before_install: cd project
```

And that worked

Comment: Thanks for the answer. npm install should be run after "cd".

Comment: Here's why : https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#The-Build-Lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

Adding below on your .travis.yml file should do it:

```
before_script: cd <project_name>
script:
  - sbt compile
  - sbt test
```

Answer (score -2):

In your yml file, add a "`cd sub-folder`" step, before you run the build command:

```
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - cd project
          - sbt ++$TRAVIS_SCALA_VERSION package
```

Example for gradle projects:

```
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - cd project
          - chmod +x gradlew
          - ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

This will fix an error like `"chmod: cannot access 'gradlew': No such file or directory"`, if the `gradlew` file is in a different folder to the git root.

It will also work in other build systems that use yml files, like [bitbucket-pipelines.yml](https://medium.com/rocknnull/setup-android-continuous-integration-ci-for-bitbucket-in-1-minute-9b72a4f1d745).

Comment: The question was about Travis, not Bitbucket Pipelines.